# Does h1 require header as parent?

Tags: html, semantics, heading

Does a h1 tag always needs a header tag?

Like the following?

```
<main>
    <header>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </header>
</main>
```

Or is this enough?

```
<main>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</main>
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html. `Permitted parent elements:
Any element that can contain flow elements, hgroup`

Answer (score 1):

"Does h1 require header as parent?" NO, it doesn't

"A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading (an h1–h6 element), but this is not required."
source: [web spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-header-element)

see also [h1 parents](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/h1_h6/html5_h1_h6_tags_nested.php)

Answer (score 0):

Its not mandatory. But semantically, its good.

Check this [link](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Any html tag does not need a parent except the table and form tags.

As long as your `<h1></h1>` is within the `<body></body>` Tags everything works fine.

But: You shouldn't put any content in the  tags, just imports and metadata!

So this is perfectly fine

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1> Text </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To be pedantic, only the `<html>` tag must not have a parent!  `<h1>` must be a descendant of `<body>`, not `<html>`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, every other tag must be within the `<head>` oder `<body>` tags. I'll edit my answer